# Como desencriptar un archivo encriptado con c#

Tags: c#, encriptación

vuelvo a ustedes a pedirles ayuda.
Estoy realizando un código que me permita encriptar y desemcriptar un archivo, para ello estoy utilizando el lenguaje C# y RijndaelManaged, en el momento me permite el encriptado, pero cuando quiero desencriptar el archivo , me genera el siguiente error.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.'
```

El relleno no es válido y no se puede eliminar.

Y no se como solucionar este problema, agradecería si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace Encriptado
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        // DESDE AQUI VA EL CÓDIGO//

        byte[] encriptar(byte[] bytesaescriptar, byte[] clave)

        {
            byte[] bytesEncriptados = null;
            byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())

            {
                using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
                // using (RijndaelManaged? aes = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(clave, salt, 1000);
                    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
                    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using (var crp = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        crp.Write(bytesaescriptar, 0, bytesaescriptar.Length);
                        crp.Close();
                    }
                    bytesEncriptados = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return bytesEncriptados;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var file = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var data = file.FileName;
                byte[] archivoaescriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(data);
                byte[] clave = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MICLAVEMICLAVE12");
                clave = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(clave);
                byte[] archivoEncriptado = encriptar(archivoaescriptar, clave);
                File.WriteAllBytes(data, archivoEncriptado);
                MessageBox.Show("Archivo : " + file.FileName + " encriptado");
            }

        }


        //  DESENCRIPTADO //
        byte[] desencriptar(byte[] bytesADesencriptar, byte[] clave)
        {
            byte[] bytesEncriptados = null;
            byte[] salt = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var aes = new RijndaelManaged())
                // using (RijndaelManaged? aes = new RijndaelManaged())
                {
                    aes.KeySize = 256;
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    //aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;


                    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(clave, salt, 1000);
                    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(aes.KeySize / 8);
                    aes.IV = key.GetBytes(aes.BlockSize / 8);
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                    using (var crp = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        crp.Write(bytesADesencriptar, 0, bytesADesencriptar.Length);
                        crp.Close();

                    }

                    bytesEncriptados = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return bytesEncriptados;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var file = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
                var data = file.FileName;
                byte[] archivoaescriptar = File.ReadAllBytes(data);
                byte[] clave = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("MICLAVEMICLAVE12");
                clave = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(clave);
                byte[] archivoEncriptado = desencriptar(archivoaescriptar, clave);
                File.WriteAllBytes(data, archivoEncriptado);
                MessageBox.Show("Archivo : " + file.FileName + " desencriptado");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: estás generando una clave diferente para descifrar. **MAL**

Estimado. Sugiero muy respetuosamente que pases un rato por algún artículo, sin importar si es el más básico, y revises cómo funciona el cifrado que intentas usar. Sin el concepto claro, estarás escribiendo código a ciegas y sin entender nada de lo que está pasando. De paso, vas a controlar mejor el resultado de tu código.

Si tienes un archivo A, lo cifras para generar un archivo cifrado A' y quieres obtener de vuelta A, usas una estrategia de cifrado donde tienes una llave que te permite recuperar lo cifrado. Como no tendría sentido que haya más de un diseño de llave que abra tu puerta, no tiene sentido que haya más de una llave que descifre tu archivo (no sería muy seguro, no?)

La clave del asunto es, pues, que debes usar el mismo resultado (*la misma clave, simplificando*) para cifrar y descifrar (el mismo par de claves, lo que sea que generes al comienzo de todo para cifrar el archivo).

Tu código para descifrar vuelve y hace `var key = new RFCblablabla` y pues, estás pidiéndole a tu vecino que te preste la llave de su casa para abrir tu puerta. O la puerta del banco. Bueh, ya se entiende.

Cuando instancias la clase donde cifras y descifras, debes arrancar por generar la herramienta (clave, claves, etc) de cifrado que vas a usar siempre. O la guardas en un archivo pa usarla después. Si te fijas, así funciona todo, los certificados en los sitios web, los keystores que usas en las aplicaciones... todo parte de guardar las llaves del reino en sitios donde puedas reusarlas.